# Passing value to subquery in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to collect all the families who live in states surrounding the user specified state by name. As you can see below. However I get this error when I execute the code and I'm not sure how to resolve it:

**error**:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "x"
LINE 13:  families WHERE state_name IN x.names and family_name...
```

**code**:

```
with x as (
    SELECT 
        bordering_states_names as names
    FROM 
        states 
    WHERE 
        state_name = 'Ohio' 
)
SELECT 
    family_name,
    state_name
FROM 
    families WHERE state_name IN x.names and family_name IS NOT NULL
LIMIT 20
```

In this case the value of bordering_states_names looks like this:

```
{"Ohio", "Indiana", "West Virginia", "Pennsylvania"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table `x` should exist with a `FROM part` for the below query, otherwise `x` might have no-sense.

So, Joining those tables ( `families` and `x` ) might be an option as in the following case :

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT 
        bordering_states_names as names
    FROM 
        states 
    WHERE 
        state_name = 'Ohio' 
)
SELECT f.family_name, f.state_name
  FROM families f inner join x
    ON ( f.state_name = x.names ) 
   AND family_name IS NOT NULL
 LIMIT 20;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite it as:

```
with x as (
    SELECT bordering_states_names as names
    FROM states 
    WHERE state_name = 'Ohio' 
)
SELECT family_name,
       state_name
FROM families 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM x WHERE state_name = ANY (names))
  AND family_name IS NOT NULL
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: could you explain a little on what is going on?

Comment: whats does this line (SELECT 1 FROM x WHERE state_name = ANY (names)) mean? SELECT 1?

Comment: @JokerMartini If state_name is element of array (check with =ANY)) then return 1. EXISTS checks subquery return rows if yes, then it means that state_name IN x.names